# Comparing a column value to all its leading values within dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data consisting of a single vector / column in a tibble:

```
my_tibble <- tibble(score = c(1,2,3,4,9,8,7,6,5,4))
```

For every row of my_tibble$score I want to calculate the difference to the largest "leading" element in the same column. This new column shall be called "difference". For example, the first row of difference should be 1 - 9, while the fifth row should be 9 - 8, and the last row will turn NA, as there is no value coming behind/below the 4.

In the end, the new tibble should look like this:

```
score | difference
<dbl>   <dbl>
1         -8
2         -7
3         -6
4         -5
9          1
8          1
7          1
6          1
5          1
4         NA
```

I want to achieve this using dplyr and have so far tried many variations of mutate like

```
my_tibble %>%
 mutate(difference = score[which(score > score)])
```

Hoping to find some way that the second "score" in the which funtction refers to the current row being mutated. However I was unsuccessfull after hours of trying and desperately searching for a solution online.

The closest I found was [dplyr: Summing n leading values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808908/dplyr-summing-n-leading-values), however that still leaves me with the problem that I want the difference to the maximum leading value of all leading values, not only of the closest n leading values.

Help and/or referral to whereever this has been answered or addressed before is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_tibble %>%
  mutate(difference = c(map_dbl(seq_along(score)[-n()], ~ score[.x] - max(score[-(1:.x)])), NA))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   score difference
   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1         -8
 2     2         -7
 3     3         -6
 4     4         -5
 5     9          1
 6     8          1
 7     7          1
 8     6          1
 9     5          1
10     4         NA
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
my_tibble <- my_tibble %>%
 mutate(difference = map_dbl(seq_along(score), function(y) ifelse(y == length(score),
 NA_real_, score[y] - max(c(score[-(1:y)])))))
```

**Output**

```
> my_tibble
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   score difference
   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1         -8
 2     2         -7
 3     3         -6
 4     4         -5
 5     9          1
 6     8          1
 7     7          1
 8     6          1
 9     5          1
10     4         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

similar with a for loop

```
  my_tibble$plouf <- NA
  N <- dim(my_tibble)[1]
  for(i in 1:N){
    my_tibble$plouf[i] <- max(my_tibble[(i+1):N,"score"])
  }
  
  my_tibble %>%
    mutate(diif = score - plouf)


   score plouf  diif
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     9    -8
 2     2     9    -7
 3     3     9    -6
 4     4     9    -5
 5     9     8     1
 6     8     7     1
 7     7     6     1
 8     6     5     1
 9     5     4     1
10     4    NA    NA
```